# Parse error while converting PYC to PY in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, decompiling, pyc

I am decrypting a pyc file to py using [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/)

The python version was 3.7.7

```
import os
import uncompyle6
file_directory = 'E:\ABCD\EFGH'
for directory_path, b, file_names in os.walk(file_directory):
    for file_name in file_names:
        if not file_name.endswith('.pyc'):
            continue

        file_path = directory_path + '/' + file_name
        original_file_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
        original_file_path = directory_path + '/' + original_file_name + '.py'
        with open(original_file_path, 'w') as f:
            uncompyle6.decompile_file(file_path, f)
```

the size of .pyc file is 31 kb ([PYC file available here](https://github.com/abhilashsinghimd/AASD_Geojson/blob/main/FILE_MANAGER.pyc?raw=true))

But I am getting this error.

```
Exception in ifelsestmt '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
rule: ifelsestmt ::= testexpr stmts jf_cfs \e_else_suite_opt \e_opt_come_from_except
offsets 7582_7584 .. 7664_0
None
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\parsers\reducecheck\ifelsestmt.py", line 176, in ifelsestmt
    if last_token == "COME_FROM" and tokens[first].offset > last_token.attr:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\parsers\parse37base.py in reduce_is_invalid(self, rule, ast, tokens, first, last)
   1204             if fn:
-> 1205                 return fn(self, lhs, n, rule, ast, tokens, first, last)
   1206         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\parsers\reducecheck\ifelsestmt.py in ifelsestmt(self, lhs, n, rule, ast, tokens, first, last)
    175             last_token = tokens[last]
--> 176         if last_token == "COME_FROM" and tokens[first].offset > last_token.attr:
    177             if self.version < 3.0 and self.insts[self.offset2inst_index[last_token.attr]].opname != "SETUP_LOOP":

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

ParserError: --- This code section failed: ---

 L.   3         0  LOAD_CONST               0
                2  LOAD_CONST               None
                4  IMPORT_NAME              os
                6  STORE_NAME               os


 L.1779  21036_21038  LOAD_CODE                <code_object clear>
         21040_21042  LOAD_STR                 'clear'
            21044  MAKE_FUNCTION_0          'Neither defaults, keyword-only args, annotations, nor closures'
         21046_21048  STORE_NAME               clear

 L.1785  21050_21052  LOAD_NAME                clear
            21054  CALL_FUNCTION_0       0  ''
            21056  POP_TOP          

Parse error at or near `COME_FROM' instruction at offset 7664
```

As the PYC file can not be edited in any text editor,

How to rectify this?

Comment: if you remove the whole ```with``` you still get an error? could you print the output of ```original_file_path```? I think the you mix-up the path separator: ```file_directory``` is Windows style but for ```file_path``` you use a Linux style. Use the ```os.path.join``` module to avoid cross-platform problems

Comment: Hiii @cards, the file_path works fine, The code converted all other .pyc files in the directory, but this error showed up for this single pyc file only. That's why I have attached the .pyc in this question,  which can be downloaded. However, You may test the code with any dummy pyc, it should work.